# How can I agree with this sentence?

Tags: negation

I sometimes find hard to understand negation in Eng sentences especially when I do some tests. Could you help me to sort out this problem please.

- The bad weather stopped us from finishing the game so we were unable to continue the match.
- ……

  1. So did we.
  2. Neither were they.
  3. They were either
  4. So were we.

I chose answer 2 but the key shows 4. Why?

Comment: The echo sentence 'So were we' matches '[W]e were unable to continue the match', but it doesn't sound idiomatic to my British ears. I'd expect a paraphrased echo such as 'We were rained off too.' The given sentence has more than a hint of redundancy; some tests are better avoided.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It sounds perfectly fine to my Russian ear. It matches and it's the correct answer.

Comment: @Sovereign Sun I suspect that I have more practice in judging idiomaticity in English. I wouldn't presume, of course, to suggest to you what sounds natural in your mother tongue.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I wasn't speaking about idiomaticity. And I didn't want to offend you but why do you think **so were we** isn't a good answer. Why do you want an idiomatic answer in there?

Comment: @Sovereign The primary (and hence default, and the one I'm assuming will be understood on a site aimed at English linguists) sense of 'idiomatic' is 'sounding natural to and commonly used by proficient Anglophones'. I'd assume anyone echoing 'The bad weather stopped us from finishing the game so we were unable to continue the match.' (which is itself very clumsy; I'd expect 'The weather got so bad we were unable to continue the match.') with 'So were we' not to be a fluent native speaker. 'That's what happened in our match too', perhaps.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You are confusing English with English used in tests. In Russia it's much worth with tests, they still teach us **How do you do**, **Would you be so kind as to**, **Farewell** and say it's okay to speak like that in English. Tests are even worth than can be. They give us a question that has three correct answers out of four. Or such which haven't a correct answer.

Comment: They teach us royal English and think everyone in GB and US speaks like that.

Comment: @SovereignSun ELU and ELL are intended for analysing real English, not the misconceptions of foreign examiners.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No, ELL helps people analys all kinds of English and correct what is wrong.

Comment: @SovereignSun 'It sounds perfectly fine to my Russian ear. It matches and it's the correct answer.' is hardly going to help people speak English in the way native speakers do; as even you admit, there is a real difference between  'English [and] 'English' used in [these] tests'. ELL is aimed at promoting the understanding and use of standard English, not that taught in many (especially older) textbooks (including some printed in the UK and US) and not the _English used in these tests_.

Comment: @SovereignSun "It sounds perfectly fine to my Russian ear. It matches and it's the correct answer." is hardly going to help people speak English in the way native speakers do; as even you admit, there is a real difference between "_English_ [and] _'English' used in [these] tests_". ELL is aimed at promoting the understanding and use of standard English, not that taught in many (especially older) textbooks (including some printed in the UK and US) and not the _English used in these tests_.

Answer (score 1):

In your sentence **The bad weather stopped us from finishing the game so we were unable to continue the match.** the construction **we were unable** with **neither** would create a double negative - **Neither were we unable** meaning **We were able** that's why we use the positive **So were we** - **We too were unable**.

If it were **The bad weather stopped us from finishing the game so we weren't able to continue the match.** then **Neither were we** would be the correct answer; **Neither were we able** meaning **We weren't able also**. The **So were we** wouldn't be correct since it would mean **We too were able**.

As for the other 3 answers:

1. **So did we** can't be the correct answer, in order for it to be one we need to rephrase the sentence **The bad weather stopped us from finishing the game so we discontinued the match.**
2. **Neither were they** is also incorrect. Since **The bad weather stopped us from finishing the game so we were unable to continue the match.** is like the second example that I described.
3. **They were either** is plain wrong.

Comment: Feel free to correct me.

Comment: Thanks alot for your comment. I could't contact you personally though. I am new here.